# How do I override the emoji url?

Tags: urls, emoji

When you enable emojis, Wordpress includes code which converts the chars to the PNGs which it pulls from a CDN.

We would like to replace those with our own images.

According to formatting.php the function is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_staticize_emoji/).

How do we override the `emoj_url` so that we are pulling the PNGs from a folder of our choosing? Can the function being replaced (ie. is it pluggable?) I tried `remove_all_filters()` and `apply_filter()` with our own function, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code, you should be able to filter it. Something like the following should do it:

```
add_filter( 'emoji_url', 'wpse_232874_emoji_cdn_url' );
function wpse_232874_emoji_cdn_url( $url ) {
    return 'http://example.com/my/cdn/url/';
}
```

...replacing `http://example.com/my/cdn/url/` with whatever URL you want to use.

### Reference

- [Plugin API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/)

Comment: That gets me most of the way there. What's weird is that the ALT tag is still replaced with the default pngs.

Comment: From what I can see, the `alt` text isn't filterable. You may be stuck there.